# Regex used to split a text based on space delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am trying to split a string by spaces, except when the token is between quotation marks. However, the code I have written also splits the string on the `.` character, which I do not want. Here is my code:

```
string txt = "PROGRAM \"My ETABS\" VERSION \"9.7.4\" MERGETOL 0.1";

string[] split = Regex.Matches(txt, "(\\w+|\".*?\")")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .Select(o => o.Replace("\"", ""))
                      .ToArray();
```

What I get:

```
PROGRAM  
My ETABS
VERSION 
9.7.4"  
MERGETOL
0
1
```

What I need:

```
PROGRAM  
My ETABS
VERSION 
9.7.4"  
MERGETOL
0.1
```

How can I modify this code to split the string by spaces, unless the token is between quotation marks, without splitting on the `.` character?

Comment: It looks like you would be better off with a CSV parser set to allow values enclosed in quotes and with the separator set to space.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks Andrew. Can you please recommend me a good one that can handle these cases?

Comment: I would stay away from a _CSV_ parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the sub expressions then substitute `\S` in place of `\w` and
it should work.  `(".*?"|\S+)`

To do it without capturing the quotes, this `"(.*?)"|(\S+)` where only
one group will contain data. For this you'd need a find next until done.
Each find you can concat the two groups.

Comment: Since `"` is a single-character, wouldn't `("[^"]*"|\S+)` be better?

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Better? I don't know. They are different. I could benchmark the two if you think that would make a difference.

Comment: Completed iterations:   300  /  300     ( x 1000 )  Matches found per iteration:   6  Regex1:   ("[^"]*"|\S+)  Elapsed Time:    2.99 s,   2988.36 ms,   2988362 µs  Regex2:   (".*?"|\S+)  Elapsed Time:    2.87 s,   2873.48 ms,   2873477 µs

Comment: As the saying goes, `touché`. I thought it would be better of being able to skip the lazy quantifier. Anyway, either variant, this is the better answer imo.